# why doesn't Java have "deep" wildcard import?

Tags: java, import, wildcard

Why doesn't `import one.two.*` include `import one.two.three.MyClass`?
Shouldn't Java have something like `import one.two.**`? Or is there any reason (other than they just didn't do, not that they couldn't do it)?

Thanks

Comment: I don't even use a single layer of package.* If I'm honest because thats the way my IDE puts them in, but it does make where classes came from clearer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java does not treat packages as truly subclassing each other; while `java.util` and `java.util.concurrency` might look like the second is somehow part of the first, they are treated as entirely independent and the dot is mostly there for neatness.

This means you don't need to be afraid of naming your class or interface the same as another one declared in some super- or sub-package on a later date, and it also means you should really just write a couple extra lines of imports.

The reasons behind this decision, as Peter Lawrey explained, stem from Java's general lean towards simplicity. Best practice is often to never use import wildcards at all anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Java treats each package as independent.  For example, package local don't extend to any "sub" packages.  I suspect using the hierarchy in a meaningful way would be valuable but Java's design was to make everything as simple as possible.

> Or is there any reason (other than they just didn't do, not that they couldn't do it)?

The problem is backward compatibility which might break older programs.  I suspect this is solvable.

In truth, most IDEs manage your imports for you and I don't even look at my imports any more.  Certainly avoiding `import *` is preferable so that all classes are explicitly imported.